# Any offset of an element returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

So I have an `svg#cta-scroll` image which is a child of `div#main`. Whenever I try to get `offsetTop` (or any other kind of offset) of the `svg`, it always returns `undefined` (Chrome, OS X).

```
(function hideCtaWelcomeOnScroll() {
  var ctaWelcomeElement = document.getElementById('cta-scroll');
  var initialCtaWelcomeOffset = ctaWelcomeElement.offsetTop;
})();
```

`initialCtaWelcomeOffset` here always returns `undefined`.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

EDIT: I don't think it'll help much but here's the CSS for the `svg`:

```
#cta-scroll
  width: 2vw
  display: block
  fill: white
  margin-left: -1vw
  position: absolute
  bottom: 7vh
  left: 50%
  z-index: 10
  animation: ctaScroll 10s infinite
```

In an act of desperation, I tried removing the animation and the positioning but it doesn't change a thing...

Comment: Just a hunch, but it might be that you didn't read [ask]??

Comment: @Amit What do you mean?

Comment: Guess it's too much code. I was in a hurry and grabbed the whole function. Sorry for that. I removed the unnecessary listener and indicated the variable that returns `undefined`.

Comment: Is the `#cta-scroll` element on the page at the point this runs?

Comment: @DBS Yes. It's static. The reference works (`ctaWelcomeElement` returns the svg). It's the `offsetTop` that causes problems.

Comment: A quick google gives me the impression that `offsetTop` isn't a valid property of an SVG element. Which is a little weird, but if you have a container element perhaps you could get the offset of that?

Comment: @DBS Oh my God, it works when wrapped in a `div` indeed! It didn't even cross my mind this might be the case. Thank you for that. Could you post this as a solution below?

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since SVG elements don't support the `offsetTop` property, you would be best off wrapping the SVG in a div and getting of the offset of that element instead.

e.g.

```
(function hideCtaWelcomeOnScroll() {
  var ctaWelcomeElement = document.getElementById('svgWrapper');
  var initialCtaWelcomeOffset = ctaWelcomeElement.offsetTop;
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="svgWrapper">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```